# Magento 2 : DHL shipping is not giving rates for UAE webite

Tags: magento2, shipping, dhl

I am using my DHL credentials in my UAE based magento website. The problem is I am not receiving any shipping rate when I select country UAE. For India and United states I receive rate. As far as I know, zip code is not applicable in UAE and DHL needs zip code with country to calculate rates. Does anybody have an idea how to get DHL working for a UAE magento website?

Comment: same issue did you find solution?